# How to Schedule Selenium Web Drivers Tests in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, scheduling

In my development project, We implemented regression test cases using selenium webdriver using c#. I would like to schedule of Regression tests once in a day. 
Tools used shows below.

1. Selenium Webdriver on C#
2. Visual Studio 2017
3. NUnit test framework

Please suggest any other solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can schedule a job in windows task scheduler to run a the test case using NUnit.exe.

Comment: Build the project and use the dll generated with Nunit-Console.exe to run the same.

Command Line documentation: http://nunit.org/docs/2.5.9/consoleCommandLine.html
NUnit console installer location: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases

Comment: Any thoughts on using Jenkins? You do not go into detail if this is a local project you are working on or if it is company driven? If you create a Jenkins instance, you can start working towards CI/CD.

Comment: @VivekNatarajan Then How will we schedule the test case run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found an exact solution for my scenario.

Tools is used:

1. NUnit3 Console. Location: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases

2. Windows Task Scheduler

 Download NUnit.Console-*.msi file.

 Install exe file. 

Create an nunit command to run your tests:

> nunit3-console testsfile.dll

More details here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Next, create the scheduled task

List item

 1. Open Task Scheduler
 2. Under Actions, Click Create a Basic Task
 3. Provide a descriptive name
 4. Choose the starting date and time.
 5. Choose Start a Program as the type of action
 6. In Program/Script add nunit3-console
 7. In Arguments add testsfile.dll
 7. In Start in add nunit3 console location
 8. Click Finish.

Now it will run on the schedule you provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use task scheduler;

1. Create a batch file with the command to execute the tests (e.g ..\nunit.exe ..\seleniumTests.cs)
2. Open 'Task Scheduler'
3. Create a task with the time/frequency as the 'Trigger' and the set the batch file as the 'Action' to execute.

Comment: Have we any other options rather than 'Task Scheduler'?

Comment: The other options will be to look at a CI tool like Jenkins, alternative use a script as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861172/how-to-schedule-running-a-bat-file-not-using-windows-task-scheduler or https://superuser.com/questions/1273449/automatically-running-a-program-without-task-scheduler