# How to send result file after all tests run in nunit console c#

Tags: selenium, nunit-console

Is there a way to send a mail with result file (I set this file in console command with option --result) after running.

I have run my selenium test cases in following way

[How to Schedule Selenium Web Drivers Tests in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341669/how-to-schedule-selenium-web-drivers-tests-in-c-sharp)

The result file was created after OneTimeTearDown function.

If sending an e-mail into OneTimeTearDown function - the result file comes incomplete

Thanks in advance
Sangeetha P.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd actually recommend doing this - but I think it's possible. Personally, I'd instead handle the email sending outside of the NUnit console, in a separate script in your CI System.

Anyway. You could achieve this by writing your own [ResultWriter](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Result-Writers) extension. Take a look at the implementation of the standard [NUnit3XmlResultWriter](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/aaef18fb80c1a656d0ff194fd0039107cf55de12/src/NUnitEngine/nunit.engine/Services/ResultWriters/NUnit3XmlResultWriter.cs) as an idea - you'd essentially want the same thing, except to send the file by email, rather than write a file. (You may even want to make your ResultWriter actually inherit the NUnit3XmlResultWriter class.)